# Multilevel object Destructuring in ES6

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

If I have the below object,

```js
const obj = {
   user:
   {
    type:{
      type1:"developer",
      type2:"architect"
    },
    role:"admin"
   },
   salary:50000
}

const {user: {type}} = obj;
console.log(`type:  ${type}`);
console.log(user);
```

and if I write something like below,

```
const {user: {type}} = obj;
console.log(type);  //prints [object Object] which is right
```

but if I try to print

```
console.log(user); // ReferenceError: user is not defined
```

can someone please explain me the below syntex of ES6 destructuring?

```
const {user: {type}} = obj;
```

Comment: You're only assigning the names that *aren't* followed by a colon.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your point a bit please?

Comment: It's unclear what else you'd like to know, your example demonstrates exactly how it works.

Comment: Actually I am not able to wrap my head around the below syntex . const {user: {type}} = obj; ..  can you please explain?

Comment: It's the same as `const type = obj.user.type;`. Your example illustrates this for you.

Comment: normally when we destruct an object we write something like const {user} = obj;  so the main object would be at right side and destructured section at left.  but when we do this chaining...this sequence reverse. I am not sure, if I am putting my question properly. but hope you get the point of confusion.

Comment: It's unclear what you think is reversed. You *still* have the name you're destructuring to on the left of the equals and the thing you're destructuring from on the right.

Comment: I am ,kind of, wrapping my head around it a bit but just one last point,  when we write something like const {user: {type}} = obj; , why the "user" property is undefined?  is it the only last level value, in the destructure chain, would be available?

Comment: Only the "leaves" at the tips of the "branches", yes. That's what I said above; only the ones that aren't followed by a colon.

Comment: got it. Thank You for the quick response.

Comment: @Akash Writeing `const {user} = obj;` is short for `const {user: user} = obj;`. The right hand side of the colon is the target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, what you're doing is you're taking the `user` sub-object, and extracting the `type` from it. It's easier if you think about it like a function - when you destructure
out properties, the original object isn't saved anywhere and is no longer accessible. Same here - `user` isn't accessible anymore.

What you could do if you wanted to access it would be to extract `type` from `user`, and also extract `user` and keep it.

```js
const obj = {
  user: {
    type: {
      type1: "developer",
      type2: "architect"
    },
    role: "admin"
  },
  salary: 50000
}

const { user: { type }, user } = obj;
console.log(`type:  ${type}`);
console.log(user);
```